# Transcribing marriage record from Gilfershausen in 1761

Tags: germany, palaeography, marriage-records, church-records, kurrent

I could use some assistance with obtaining a transcription for this image.  This marriage entry is from the Iba/Gilfershausen Kirchenbuch 1742-1773.  The handwriting is pretty poor overall, and this entry I find quite difficult to read.

[image]

In [Amt Rotenburg: Trauregister von Kurhessen und Waldeck, Band 4.1](https://www.amazon.ca/Amt-Rotenburg-Thomas-Blumenstein/dp/3735779492), Thomas Blumenstein abstracted the essential details as:

```
05.04.1761
Schade?, Conrad, aus Krumsbach?
, Dorothea
B.: Buße abgenommen
```

However, I believe the surname to read "Schwitzer", not "Schade".  As for where he was from, it looks like "aus dem [something]".  There was a Schweitzer family in Gilfershausen a few decades earlier, though I have no record of a Conrad among them.  I do have a few other Conrads that could potentially be this one, from Cornberg, Hasselbach, Rockensüß, or Weiterode, though none of those villages' names seem to fit whatever is written there.

Answer (score 2):

Quite difficult... here's what I think is in the entry, hopefully other people can comment on that ("?" marks words I'm not sure, "..." are word parts or words I'm completely unsure about).

> Den 5 Apr 1761 wurde Conrad Schwitz...? aus dem ... für? ... abgenommen? mit Vorbehalt wann? er ... wird? ..essen [fassen?] ... ... Verordnung? ...zunahm? und Kirchs...beruhtie...t?

PS: This seems like the "which legal documents were presented" part of a marriage entry to me. Is there maybe additional information on this in another entry (possible in another parish)?

Comment: In theory, this should be the marriage register's marriage entry itself - or at least, that's the section of the church book that it's in.  It's possible that there was a legal document presented, though I've not seen that noted in any other records here or in nearby towns - permission and taxes were generally required before people could move between towns.  I've also not found any other record elsewhere that might match with this one, though it'd narrow that search significantly if the town he were from (assuming it wasn't Gilfershausen) could be identified...

Comment: ... https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1_cHy99goGI3DEpQ_6ma9HSY9CxEXQ26H&usp=sharing visualizes the towns I've so far read through the church books for Schweitzer entries; bright green, olive green, and orange identify towns in which Schweitzers were found.  There were two adult male Schweitzers in Gilfershausen at the time for whom I've not found marriages; Johannnes Schweitzer and Conrad Heinrich Schweitzer.  It'd be odd for the latter to be this same Conrad Schweitzer, however; the priests were generally quite good about giving the entire name, even if sometimes abbreviated.

Comment: In case anyone wants to dig around in that part of the Schweitzer tree, here's the entry for Conrad Heinrich: https://www.ancestry.com/family-tree/person/tree/179271094/person/182336023936/facts

Comment: The placename part could also be read as "auf dem Krank(en)bett seine ..." - from a sickbed. The rest is unclear, the ending seems to be "dieses ist berechtigt?". I can't see any other name besides his own there, so it cannot be a marriage record, but rather perhaps a note to some other entry?

Comment: Very interesting comment, @CuriousM ! BrianFreud, are there other entries around this one that are not strictly marriage records? In some parishes the different records were mixed and ordered purely chronologically.